# Showing data in textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get data from a database (which I have done and know that works)
However I want to push the data into a variable.

I can not see what is wrong, at the moment there is a mistake around "cmd.select" so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

```
  Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
  Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
  Dim sqladp As New SqlDataAdapter()
  Dim ds As New DataSet()
  cmd.Parameters.Clear()

  cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PemcoConnectionString").ConnectionString
  cmd.Connection = cn

  GridView2.Visible = True
  cmd.Connection = cn
  cmd.CommandText = "spUserResultsDetails"
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  Session.Item("ID") = (sender.SelectedValue.ToString)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Session.Item("ID"))

  For Each datarow As Data.DataRowView In cmd.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
      sEmailAddress = datarow("UserEmail")
  Next

  sqladp.SelectCommand = cmd
  sqladp.Fill(ds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that need improvement, this should work:

```
Using cn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PemcoConnectionString").ConnectionString))
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("spUserResultsDetails", cn)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CInt(Session.Item("ID")))
        Dim table = New Data.DataTable()
        da.Fill(table)
        GridView2.DataSource = table
        GridView2.DataBind()
    End Using
End Using
```

A summary:

- use the using statement always to ensure that disposable objects are getting disposed (closed)  even on error
- use a `SqldataAdapter` if you want to fill a `DataTable`, you don't need to open/close it with fill, use it's `SelectCommand` property to get a reference to the `SqlCommand`
- set the table as `DataSource` of your `GridView` and DataBind it
- if you use `AddWithValue` you should cast the passed objects to the correct type, otherwise the correct type cannot be inferred